# How to detect if a string is in the ruby on rails path env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have rack middleware that gets the path:

```
path = env["PATH_INFO"]
```

I then check the path and act accordingly.

```
if (path != '/')
```

I would like to add logic so that if the URL does not equal `/landing/XXXX`

Where `XXXX` is dynamic? How can I do this with ruby on rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if path != "/landing/#{your_code_here}"
  ...
end

if path[0,9] != "/landing/"
    ....
end
```

Comment: What is your code? I would like the XXXX to be anything, Just have it match the /landing part of the url?

Comment: Ok, see my edit.  Also, consult the docs and tutorials on the ruby String class.

Answer (score 2):

Any of these work

```
PATH_PREFIX = '/landing/'

if path !~ /^#{PATH_PREFIX}/

if path[0,PATH_PREFIX.length] != PATH_PREFIX

if path.index(PATH_PREFIX) != 0
```